# Using Arduino to activate a switch on a separate device with a different voltage

Tags: arduino, switches, power-electronics, esp32

Trying to figure out how to use an Arduino or ESP32F board (3.3V) to activate a button on a remote control fob.

The fob is powered by two coin-cell batteries (CR2016 3V) in series. It measures ~ 6.5V and [data sheet](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2016.pdf) says each battery is 100 mAh.

When I look at the voltage as the button is pressed, it looks like it brings it down to 0, from ~ 6.5V.

Can I use my Arduino board to activate the switch by adding a resistor between the button and the Arduino board and having the related pin bring the signal down?

Not sure how to approach solving this problem

Comment: Do both systems need to be isolated? If not then simply drive a transistor (BJT or an NMOS) to pull the respective line to ground. Fob's and Arduino's (or ESP32's) grounds need to be connected together.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Makes sense to use a transistor. I don't follow about the grounds needing to be connected together though. Would I tie the transistor ground with the arduino and with the fob or something else?

Comment: Without connecting the grounds together, voltages at both sides (ESP and fob) will be meaningless. Without connecting grounds together, the 6.5V on the fob will not be seen as 6.5V by the ESP. So you won't be able to tie the end to ground with a transistor. You can still use a relay or an optocoupler to keep the ends isolated, though.

Comment: @RohatKılıç thanks, that makes sense. If you want to write this up as an answer, I can accept it so you get credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do:

- Use a semiconductor switch (BJT or MOSFET) with a direct connection

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx1LjV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`INTERCONNECTION` above represents the connection between the nodes. It can be a wire-to-wire connector or simply a wire that connects both sides. Choose whatever you want, up to you. Also, I used M1 MOSFET (2N7002 which can be driven easily with 3.3V from ESP/Arduino) but can be a BJT such as BC547 or a similar one.

---

- Use an optoisolator (a.k.a. optocoupler) to keep both sides isolated

This would work better if you could know the pull-up resistor on `FOB_INPUT` lane but should work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmsQao.png)</sup>

---

- Use a miniature relay - again, to keep both sides isolated

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDcpfE.png)</sup>

This one is a bit more complex. Although I marked the relay supply as `ESP_VCC`, it can be any external voltage. But the relay should be one that can work with that level.